# Alternate color of ListView disappears on scrolling the screen in Android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, view

I am using ListView with alternate rows colored. But when the ListView exceeds the length of the screen, on scrolling, the alternate color disappears.
Below is my code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
                .inflate(R.layout.problem_list_row, null);
        if(position%2!=0) {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ebebeb"));
        }
    }
    if(position%2!=0){
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ebebeb"));
    }
    /* some code */
    return convertView;
}
```

Attached below, the image of the ListView.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
            .inflate(R.layout.problem_list_row, null);

}
if(position%2==0)
{
    // SET EVEN POSITION COLOR
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ebebeb"));
}
else
{
   //SET ODD POSITION COLOR
}

/* some code */
return convertView;

}
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

`convertView` is `null` if the entire `ListView` fits on the screen. However once you start scrolling, `View`s that move off the screen get passed to the `getView()` method as `convertView`. Sometimes the `convertView` received will be grey even though you want the `View` to be white. Your code doesn't deal with this case because it only colours `View`s grey, it never clears the background colour when it is no longer wanted. To solve this problem you need to set the colour both for odd and even positions.

This should work.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
                .inflate(R.layout.problem_list_row, null);
    }
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(position%2!=0 ? "#ebebeb" : "#ffffff"));
    /* some code */
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: This is what is done above. I am using position only to check if it is even or odd.

Comment: But you're not clearing the background colour if position is even.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use multiple views, so two .xml file in your case.

I did exactly the same thing you want in an article on my website: http://raverat.github.io/android-listview-multi-views/

Hope this will help!